# Javascript Big Decimal - Nth Root

Tags: javascript, math, bigdecimal

Recently I run into the well known floating point precision errors of Javascript. Usually I would avoid floating point calculations on the thin client & rather leave it to the back-end.

I started using the [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js) library created by Michael Mclaughlin. Though it has a square-root method/function, it does not have a nth-root methods/function nor does the power function support fraction values as arguments.

So I was wondering if anyone using the library has extended it to have such a function or at least use it to calculate accurate nth-root results.

[Michael Mclaughlin](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/issues/13#issuecomment-20085782) suggested that I implement such a function similar in structure to the square-root function. However my attempts at understanding the logic proofed my maths-disability, resulting in simple calculations yielding very wrong results.

Using the algorithm on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Nth_root#JavaScript) also yields incorrect results.

So I was wondering if anyone using the library has extended it to have such a function or at least use it to calculate accurate nth-root results.

Here is the code to my last attempt:

```
P['nthrt'] = P['nthroot'] = function (n, prec)
{
    var negate, r,
        x = this,
        xc = x['c'],
        i = x['s'],
        e = x['e'];

    // Argument defaults
    n = n || 2;
    prec = prec || 12;

    // Zero?
    if ( !xc[0] ) {
        return new Big(x)
    }

    // Negative?
    negate = ( n % 2 == 1 && i < 0 );

    // Estimate.
    r = new Big(1); // Initial guess.

    for (var i = 0; i < prec; i++) {
        r = (ONE.div(n)).times(r.times(n-1).plus(x.div(r.pow(n-1))));
    }

    if (negate) r['s'] = -1;

    return r;
};
```

It does not even get obvious results correct like the 4th root of 81 = 3, instead it gets 3.00000000xxx

Comment: Rosetta Code uses Newton's method to find the root of `x^n-num` (I could be picky about it's use of `prec`ision).  Can you show us the code that is yielding incorrect results?

Comment: Added the function, thank you for the interest

Answer (score 1):

Newton's method only gives an approximation for the root, so 3.0000xxx should be expected.  If you know that the answer should be an integer, you can round `r` down (Newton's method overestimates the root) and check that `r^n=x`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [big-numbers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-numbers) library to solve your problem. They support sqrt, pow, exp and many other features.
The pow method accept positive, negative, integer and floating point numbers:

```
var bn = new BigNumber();
var value = bn.of('81');

var xRoot = value.pow(0.25);
console.log('Result: ' + bn.format(xRoot));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Basenumber.js](https://github.com/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js) to perform **nth root**. Documentation [here](https://github.com/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js/wiki).

E.g.

```js
// Set precision decimals required
Base.setDecimals(25);

let x = Base("1e+10");

console.log(x.root(10).toString());
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js@main/BaseNumber.min.js'></script>
```